# 2003 Honda CRV - automatic. Clicking noise when I hit the gas, only notice when I am under 30 mph

Tags: honda, noise, crv

Have noticed this for the past several months.  Doesn't affect driving or gas mileage at all.  Have had car in only for oil changes every 3K miles.  Am retired and am only driving about 800 miles per month.  Car has 141,000 miles on it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the noise constant, or is it just a single click when you hit the gas?

Comment: Noise is constant...a clicking or a spinning noise, very fast.